# Yii2 how to retrieve repeatable fields from database for update form

Tags: php, arrays, database, yii2

How should I go about getting data from a single database field that has been saved as a json encode array back into my yii2 update form.

I need to do some sort of foreach loop and then modify the below bit of form field code to include the current value of that within the current array.

```
    <?= $form->field($model, 'group[{{row-count-placeholder}}][name]')->textInput(['maxlength' => 255])->label('Name') ?>
```

Below is my repeatable field setup for my create form each array has the following items/form fields

```
    <?= $form->field($model, 'group[{{row-count-placeholder}}][name]')->textInput(['maxlength' => 255])->label('Name') ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'group[{{row-count-placeholder}}][url]')->textInput(['maxlength' => 255])->label('URL') ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'group[{{row-count-placeholder}}][colour]')->dropDownList(['yellow' => 'Yellow', 'blue' => 'Blue', 'green' => 'Green']); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'group[{{row-count-placeholder}}][datetime]')->textInput(['maxlength' => 255])->label('Date/Time') ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'group[{{row-count-placeholder}}][status]')->dropDownList(['normal' => 'Normal', 'Featured' => 'Featured', 'sponsored' => 'Sponsored']); ?>
```

I know a full answer in unlikely so any steps on how i'd go about developing it would be great.

Comment: That's sophisticated... a good but not exhaustive approach can be found [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/666/handling-tabular-data-loading-and-validation-in-yii-2/) or [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-tabular-input.html). `$model->loadMultiptle()` is the essential thing. That would mean you have to create repeatable model objects.

Comment: @robsch  
I may be getting confused but the examples you have linked to, do they mean each array item is saved in a separate DB or is it saved as an array into a single database field.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a second, non-AR model to represent the array items. After loading the AR model in your controller decode the field and convert the array items into models. Pass those to the view. When processing such batch form, use `loadMultiple()`. After validating all models, convert them to arrays and encode them as your main AR model attribute.